# SSRS 2005 Threshold Line in Chart

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a chart that works perfectly in Visual Studio 2008, but in 2005 I can't seem to get a certain aspect of it to work - the threshold line.  I want a solid line going straight across the chart at .04. That way, if any region goes above the threshold, it'll be easily viewable to the reader.

Now, when I do this in Visual Studio 2008, I simply add a field to the data fields section (i have a column called "threshold" in my SQL dataset, upon which this report is based - I added that to the data fields in the chart, then, I simply assigned .04 as the value in the Series Properties).  But it won't work if i do it this way in Visual Studio 2005, which is where I need to use it now, due to the fact that I am on SQL Server 2005.  (When I say it won't work, what I mean is that the threshold line doesn't show up in the chart at all.)

Definitely at a loss here - any help is very much appreciated.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question.  My threshold value was a string data type - I changed it to numeric, and the above solution that worked in 2008 now works in 2005.